# Why shouldn't I update all dependencies in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I followed these steps to create an application using template.

[image: 1]

Then, right click `References` and select `Manage Nuget Packages...` to update all dependencies:

[image: 2]

After restoring, I build the solution successful:

[image: 3]

But I couldn't create new controller, I don't know where did the error come from?

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

I'm sure that I can create new controller by using that way before updating. After updating, it's not.

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

My `project.json`:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication4-0f14c4f8-ad0e-433e-9894-4af5ea844755",

  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc":  {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I'm using VS 2015 with update 3.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've updated the `tools` based on @Tseng's comment. But I still cannot create new controller:

[image: a]

It requires dependency: `Microsoft.NetCore.App` version `1.1.0`.
I've tried to add but it's not successful:

[image: a]

It said: `Microsoft.NetCore.App` does not support .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: I think you have updated your ASP.NET Core from 1.0 to 1.1, but didn't changed the runtime (your runtime still may be `netcoreapp1.0`, but for ASP.NET Core you need `netcoreapp1.1`.

Comment: @Tseng Sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: See my answer below, for both VS2015 and the new csproj based VS2017

Comment: You can't add `Microsoft.NetCore.App` to a project targeting .NET 4.6.1. This is a meta package for `netcoreapp1.x` which references the .NET Core 1.x packages. Did you install the .NET Core runtime? http://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current. After installing, try removing the packages from dependencies section which require .NET Core (usually the `*.Tools` packages as they should be available via the SDK/Runtime installation), but keep the tools section. Only remove them from dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I can see your project.json, I see the issue: You didn't updated your tools section.

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
```

It still uses the old tools.

```
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
```

`1.1.0-preview4-final` should be the correct version last time I looked at it. Same applies for some of the dependencies in your dependencies section, like for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc`

Comment: You mean: change `net461` to `netcoreapp1.1`? I've update the question with the file `project.json`

Comment: No. Now that i see your project.json, its a different issue. See the update

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the tools based on your comment. Restore completed. But I'm getting another error. Please checking for my update 2.